# AS3 AIR TextField Glitch (flickering on TweenMax.to)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

Hey I'm wondering if anybody else is having this issue or could suggest a hack? Whenever I get too much going, like too many clips on the stage, then too many TweenMax tweens, my TextField objects will start flickering, sorta like they are rendering over and over again. It looks terrible and I'm wondering if there is some known workaround? It only seems to happen with the text, so I'm wondering if I could somehow render it as a bitmap after drawing it the first time?

This was happening earlier if I would fire off too many tweens at the same time. Now it's happening because I added filters to the containing object. Seems like if things get too intensive then the text fields start flickering. Tested this on both Mac Air and Mac Pro. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `cacheAsBitmap` on your TextFields.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#cacheAsBitmap.

There are a few threads (like this one http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?345755-TextField-with-CSS-and-cacheAsBitmap) suggesting that CSS formatting and embedded fonts get a little messed up, so you may have to experiment with the order in which you add things, set their formatting, and cache them.